# Replace null with same value per date - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to make a query that updates `VAL` by setting the same value to all the `HOUR` hours within the same `DATA` day. It has to somehow check for a value in the same date and replace the nulls with it, but I can't seem to get my head around on how to do it. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
PROCESS    DATA     HOUR    VAL
-------- ---------- ----- -------
508410   2015.03.29  19   36.15
508410   2015.03.30  11   NULL
508410   2015.03.30  14   NULL
508410   2015.03.30  15   35.36
508410   2015.03.30  23   NULL
508410   2015.03.31  11   NULL
508410   2015.03.31  12   20.4
508410   2015.04.01  01   NULL
508410   2015.04.01  02   37.06
```

How I want it to look like:

```
PROCESS    DATA     HOUR    VAL
-------- ---------- ----- -------
508410   2015.03.29  19   36.15
508410   2015.03.30  11   35.36
508410   2015.03.30  14   35.36
508410   2015.03.30  15   35.36
508410   2015.03.30  23   35.36
508410   2015.03.31  11   20.4
508410   2015.03.31  12   20.4
508410   2015.04.01  01   37.06
508410   2015.04.01  02   37.06
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `HOUR` column has to do with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is having an inline query in the `set` clause. You can utilize the fact that `max` ignores `null`s and use that to return the only non-null `val` per `data`:

```
UPDATE mytable a
SET    a.val = (SELECT MAX(val)
                FROM   mytable b
                WHERE  b.data = a.data)
WHERE  a.val IS NULL
```